# How to use the mdAutocomplete openPanel method

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to create a button that both clears an mdAutocomplete control and opens the panel.

Something like this:

```
clearValue() {
  this.stateCtrl.setValue("");
  this.trigger.openPanel();
}
```

here is a plunk for the full code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/KC8f1bHaDpWXEkLxzLta?p=preview

If I put a break point in the `clearValue` function and call `this.trigger.openPanel()` in the console the panel opens, but when I just let the code run the panel never opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easist way to solve your problem is to prevent propagation to handler that closes popup:

```
(click)="clearValue(); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3UpwZqbKnDNbnOBx99la?p=preview)**